# Deno: "Classic workers are not supported"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, worker, deno

I wanted to create a Web Worker like so:

```js
const blob = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`
  ...
`], {type: 'text/javascript'}))
const worker = new Worker(blob)
```

But when doing so in Deno I get:

```
error: Uncaught NotSupported: Classic workers are not supported.
    const worker = new Worker(blob)
                   ^
```

I've googled this message "Classic workers are not supported" and I've found basically nothing explaining the history behind it or what specifically it means. I've found a little bit about a special Deno way of creating workers:

```js
const worker = new Worker(new URL("worker.js", import.meta.url).href, {
  type: "module",
  deno: true,
});
worker.postMessage({ filename: "./log.txt" });
```

but it doesn't appear to serve my needs because I specifically need to initialize a worker dynamically from a string (or at least from an arbitrary function passed at runtime).

Is there any way to do what I need to do in Deno?

Edit: I did manage to find this page in the docs (Deno's docs have trouble turning up results in search engines, for some reason), though it doesn't bode well because it sounds like there's no way to do what I'm needing to do
https://deno.land/manual/runtime/web_platform_apis#web-worker-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deno does not currently support "classic" workers.

1. From [Worker() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker):

   > `type`: A [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) specifying the type of worker to create. The value can be `classic` or `module`. If not specified, the default used is `classic`.
2. From [Workers | Manual | Deno](https://deno.land/manual/runtime/workers):

   > Currently Deno supports only `module` type workers; thus it's essential to pass the `type: "module"` option when creating a new worker.

For your use case you might be able to use a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). e.g.:

```
new Worker(
  `data:text/javascript;base64,${btoa(
    `console.log("hello world"); self.close();`
  )}`,
  { type: "module" }
);
```

Comment: I think this did actually work. I'd tried this and it didn't work: `new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([code], {type: 'module'})))` but for whatever reason this works: `new Worker('data:text/javascript;base64,' + btoa(code) + '}', { type: "module" })`

Comment: Edit: I mentioned under another answer, but I was passing the `type` object to the wrong function here and that's why it wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

The information provided in [mfulton26's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69292184/438273) is right, but you don't need a data URL: you simply need to add `{ type: "module" }` to your worker instantiation options. Deno even supports TypeScript as the source for your worker:

`blob-worker.ts`:

```ts
const workerModuleSource = `
const version: string = Deno.version.deno;
console.log(\`Hello from Deno v\${version}\`);
self.close();
`;

const blob = new Blob(
  [workerModuleSource],
  {type: 'application/typescript'},
);

const objUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const worker = new Worker(objUrl, {
  deno: true,
  type: 'module',
});

URL.revokeObjectURL(objUrl);
```

```
$ deno run --unstable blob-worker.ts
Hello from Deno v1.14.1
```

Comment: As mentioned in my reply above, just changing the `type` didn't do it | Edit: I just noticed it was the wrong `type` field

Comment: @brundolf If you are referring to the code in [your comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69276975/deno-classic-workers-are-not-supported/69292373?noredirect=1#comment122472215_69292184), you are passing the `{ type: "module" }` options in the wrong place: it should be passed to the `Worker` constructor, not the `Blob` constructor.